# API Product with multiple words

Tags: api

I dont know how can I add multiple words search using magento 2 product api.
Example :

```
https://www.store.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=8&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%25test%20word%25&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][field]=visibility&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][value]=4
```

I tried severals things, each time I add a search name with 2 words, it does not return any result.

MAgento 2 API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your request like below.

```
https://www.store.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25test%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=%25word%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][field]=visibility&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][value]=4
```

You need to build your search criteria in OR condition. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did try that, (I just did again right now). It doesnt work for me. (No result found).

Comment: its working for me @David

Comment: You were right ! It's working, sorry about it. I did a quick mistake

Comment: Great, Happy Coding :)